# Dygrpaphs: browser not responding when showRangeSelector = true on large data set

Tags: dygraphs

When I use dygraphs on a dataset of 50,000 points it works beautifully.
However, when I try to enable the rangeSelector the browser becomes non responsive.
This does not happen when I work with a smaller dataset (~5000 points).

Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Dygraphs, there are some tips here: https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=468